# (Intel XDK) No puedo usar un formulario con accion POST para usar función PHP

Tags: php, post, intel-xdk

he desarrollado una app HTML5 y quiero usarla en Intel XDK. Todo funciona bien con una excepción, un form con accion POST para usar una función PHP que guarda una imagen seleccionada en una carpeta de la aplicación.
Cuando quiero usar esa función me sale el error:

> Cannot POST /http-services/emulator-webserver/ripple/userapp/x/C/Users/XXXXXXXXX/Documents/Proyectos/centerinformaticapp/www/guardarImg.php

¿Como puedo hacerlo funcionar?

¿Alguien puede darme un ejemplo?

Es un form comun:

```
<form id="formulario" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="guardarImg.php" method="POST">
     <input type="file" id="Imagen" name="Imagen"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Cargar">
</form>
```

Y en guardarImg.php:

```
<?php
$uploadedfileload="true";
$uploadedfile_size=$_FILES['Imagen']['size'];
echo $_FILES['Imagen']['name'];
if ($_FILES['Imagen']['size']>500000){
    $msg="El archivo es mayor que 500KB, debes reduzcirlo antes de subirlo<BR>";
    $uploadedfileload="false";
}

if (!($_FILES['Imagen']['type'] =="image/jpeg" OR $_FILES['Imagen']['type'] =="image/png")){
    $msg=" Tu archivo tiene que ser JPG o PNG. Otros archivos no son permitidos<BR>";
    $uploadedfileload="false";
}

$file_name=$_FILES['Imagen']['name'];
$add="imgProductos/$file_name";

if($uploadedfileload=="true"){
    if(move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['Imagen']['tmp_name'], $add)){
        echo " Ha sido subido satisfactoriamente";
    }else{
        echo "Error al subir el archivo";
    }
}else{
    echo $msg;
}
?>
```

Comment: Hola Alan y bienvenido! Podrías a;adir el código que tienes para poder ayudarte específicamente?

Comment: Gracias, ya lo agregué

Comment: Te falta el javascript :)

Comment: Si, se me olvidó :P pero en todo caso sería el php, ya lo añadí

Comment: Al parecer el error se puede encontrar en el path `$add = "imgProductos/$file_name";` Está bajo `__DIR__` ya verificaste que exista y tenga los permisos adecuados? Adicionalmente, ese modo de poner nombre a los archivos de destino de upload crea agujeros de seguridad.

Answer (score -1):

Intenta utilizando AJAX, es una manera mas seguroa de enviar la informacion y trabajar los procesos en segundo plano
Te recomiendo que uses $ajax de JQuery, es mas simple que usar el AJAX nativo de Javascript